# No viable Overloaded. "=" C++

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> intersect(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
     
        int k=0;
    int m=nums1.size();
        int n=nums2.size();
     vector<int> res[m];
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(nums1[i]==nums2[j]){
                    res[k]=nums1[i];
                    k++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

I had to find duplicates in two different arrays and return the same. But I'm getting the error

> no viable overloaded '='

from the compiler in the line where I am storing my duplicates in the `res[k]` vector.

Comment: res is an array of vectors. So if you assign something to res[k], it should be a vector (of ints)

Comment: `vector<int> res[m];` you probably wanted `vector<int> res(m);` which will be a single vector of m ints instead of a c style array of m empty vectors.

Comment: Side note: You do not use any members of class `Solution`, so step1: the function should rather be *static*, but then no non-static members remain thus step 2: the class should rather be a namespace and static functions get free-standing ones...

Comment: You have either have a strange understanding of `intersection` or your algorithm doesn't work as you intend: consider `{ 1, 2, 2, 2 }` and `{ 2 }`, result would be `{ 2, 2, 2 }`...

Comment: I personally would rather sort both vectors then iterate over both similarly to the merge step within merge sort: while current element of one vector is smaller than the current one in the other, skip it; if both are equal add it to the target vector and skip it in *both* source vectors.

Comment: By the way, that's already implemented: [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) (requiring sorted sources).

Answer (score 1):

In this line you try to allocate an array of `std::vector`s.

```
vector<int> res[m];
```

But `m` is not constant so it causes a compilation error (C++ does not support VLA - see [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)).

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but I believe you should change it to:

```
vector<int> res;
```

Then use `push_back` to add elements to it:

```
res.push_back(nums1[i]);    // Instead of: res[k]=nums1[i];
```

You don't need to track the number of elements in the vector with `k` and you can eliminate it altogether.

2 more notes:

1. The method `intersect` can be a static method (or a free functions) as it doesn't need access to any class members.
2. Your algorithm implementation compares each element in `nums1` to each element in `nums2` so you will get duplicates in the output array (not sure what was intended).

Comment: Got your point ! Thank you so much

Comment: To avoid multiple re-allocations you might want to add `res.reserve(std::min(n, m))`. However the duplicates problem should to be fixed before.

Comment: Good point in general @Aconcagua. Although it depends on the case. If m,n are large and but you have very few equal values (between the vectors) you'll reserve a lot more than needed.

Comment: Well, then swapping with a new vector might solve that (`shrink_to_fit` has no guarantees...) as well. One might need to measure, but in most cases/on most systems I'd expect that  single re-allocation getting cheaper than multiple ones (just for completeness...).

Comment: I agree. Measuring each typical use case is anyway a must when dealing with optimizations.

Comment: @KashishBagga consider accepting my answer by clicking the "v" below the score (if it  answered your question).